# Migrating from CoreData to Realm

Tags: core-data, realm

I'm interested in using [Realm](http://realm.io/), but I first need to migrate my SQLite Core-Data implementation over to Realm's persistent store.

Does anyone have any tips/docs on how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi Tim. I would love if you could share how you ended up accomplishing this. Same boat here : )

Comment: Wow!  It has been three years since I asked that question and we never migrated.  We just iterated over shoring up our CoreData usage and never looked at Realm again ...  Sorry I can't help any further ...

Answer (score 0):

This can help:

https://realm.io/news/migrating-from-core-data-to-realm/

I think the idea for this is to keep your old bank, and when the boot app, check if there are any records in the old model (coredate), if any, make a request of all data and save them again with Realm.

As for implementation, remove any implementation CRUD / DAO CoreData and replace with the Realm. I believe this can help.

Answer (score -2):

Take a look here:

[#adding-more-versions](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.81.0/#adding-more-versions)

I think you can read all your current model and import them into Realm

Comment: That link doesn't appear relevant to my issue.  It talks about versioning within a Realm, not from SQLite to a Realm.

Comment: You can read your CoreData or SQLite Objects, then you can write them manually on the migration block, like from 0 to 1. You can create new objects inside that block not just migrating.